# java use switch statement with values retrieved by locale

Tags: java, switch-statement, locale

I want to change my switch statement from hardcoded values to something more specific to the current locale, because the names of the languages change from language to language.

I cant change this:

```java
switch(Objects.requireNonNull(comboBox.getSelectedItem()).toString()) {
                case "Deutsch" -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE"));
                case "Englisch (UK)" -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "UK"));
                case "Englisch (US)" -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
                case "Französisch" -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr", "FR"));
}
```

Into something like that

```java
switch(Objects.requireNonNull(comboBox.getSelectedItem()).toString()) {
                case (resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.german")) -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE"));
                case (resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.english_uk")) -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "UK"));
                case (resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.english_us")) -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
                case (resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.french")) -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr", "FR"));
}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Why use a `switch` statement when you can populate and use a `Map`?

Comment: @rgettman How would I use a map in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case labels in a switch need to be a constant expression in Java. You can either replace it with an if-statement or use a Map to look up actions (`Runnable`s).

##### Approach using if

```
final String selected = Objects.requireNonNull(comboBox.getSelectedItem()).toString()
if (selected.equals(resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.german"))) {
  Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE"));
} else if (selected.equals(resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.english_uk"))) {
  Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "UK"))
} else if (selected.equals(resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.english_us"))) {
  Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"))
} else if (selected.equals(resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.french"))) {
  Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr", "FR"));
}
```

##### Approach using a lookup map

```
final Map<String, Runnable> localeActions = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry(
        resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.german"),
        () -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE"))
    ),
    Map.entry(
        resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.english_uk")
        () -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "UK"))
    ),
    Map.entry(
        resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.english_us")
        () -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"))
    ),
    Map.entry(
        resourceBundle.getString("menu.settings.language.french")
        () -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr", "FR"))
    )
);

final Runnable action = localeActions.getOrDefault(
    Objects.requireNonNull(comboBox.getSelectedItem()).toString(),
    () -> {});
action.run();
```